# How do I find the oldest date in Group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where I need to get the oldest date from a group and be able to return all rows. I'm finding it difficult since I need to return the system_id field.

```
 AssignedProfsHistory      MatterID        EffectiveDate
         1                 33434-3344       08/22/2005
         2                 33434-3344       07/12/2004
         3                 33434-3344       07/12/2004
         4                 21122-323        12/05/2007
         5                 43332-986        10/18/2014
         6                 43332-986        03/23/2013
```

So in this example, the rows for systemid 2 & 3 should return because they are tied for earliest date. The row for systemid 4 should return and systemid 6 should be returned.

This is what I have so far. Because I need to include the systemid(AssignedProfHistory) I'm not getting the results I need.

```
SELECT  aph.AssignedProfsHistory,
        m.MatterID,
        Min(aph.EffectiveDate) as 'EffectiveDate'
from AssignedProfsHistory aph
INNER JOIN Matters m
ON aph.Matters = m.Matters
WHERE aph.AssignedType = 'Originating'
Group by m.matters,m.matterid,aph.assignedprofshistory
order by m.MatterID
```

Any idea how to get the results I need?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to keep the ties, I'd do it like this:

```
SELECT t2.AssignedProfsHistory, m.MatterID, t2.EffectiveDate
FROM (
   SELECT MatterID, MIN(EffectiveDate) med 
   FROM AssignedProfsHistory 
   WHERE AssignedType = 'Originating'
   GROUP BY MatterID
) t1
INNER JOIN AssignedProfsHistory t2 ON t2.MatterID = t1.MatterID 
   and t2.EffectiveDate = t1.med and t2.AssignedType = 'Originating'
INNER JOIN Matters m on m.Matters = t2.Matters
ORDER BY m.MatterId
```

Here is an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c697/1/0) without the `Matters` table that demonstrates it can work, no windowing functions or CTE required, though a CTE would allow you to avoid repeating the `AssignedType='Originating'` condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
select AssignedProfsHistory, MatterID, EffectiveDate
from (
SELECT  
aph.AssignedProfsHistory,
m.MatterID,
aph.EffectiveDate,
row_number() over(partition by m.MatterID order by aph.EffectiveDate) as rn
from AssignedProfsHistory aph
INNER JOIN Matters m  ON aph.Matters = m.Matters
WHERE aph.AssignedType = 'Originating'
) t
where rn = 1;
```

You can use the `row_number` window function to assign row numbers to  dates for each matterid. Because the ordering is based on the ascending EffectiveDate, rows with the oldest date get assigned `1` and you select those.

If a matterid can have multiple rows with the oldest dates, you can use `rank` or `dense_rank` to get all the rows for the oldest date.

Comment: `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`, not `ROW_NUMBER`.  They want to keep ties.

Answer (score 1):

this should get you what you need

```
 with cte as (
                    SELECT  aph.AssignedProfsHistory,
                            m.MatterID,
                            aph.EffectiveDate as 'EffectiveDate'
                    from AssignedProfsHistory aph
                    INNER JOIN Matters m
                    ON aph.Matters = m.Matters
                    WHERE aph.AssignedType = 'Originating'
                    Group by m.matters,m.matterid,aph.assignedprofshistory
                ) 



    select 
        AssignedProfsHistory,
        MatterID,
        EffectiveDate
    from
        cte
        join (
                select
                    min(EffectiveDate) min_effectivedate,
                    MatterID
                from
                    cte
                group by
                    MatterID
                ) b on cte.EffectiveDate = b.min_effectivedate and 

cte.MatterID = b.MatterID


order by AssignedProfsHistory
```

Answer (score 1):

First take the older date and then join it with your table.

```
WITH OlderAPH AS (
    SELECT  
        AssignedProfsHistory,
        Matters,
        MIN(EffectiveDate) OlderDate
    FROM AssignedProfsHistory
    WHERE AssignedType = 'Originating'
    GROUP BY Matters, AssignedProfsHistory )
SELECT 
    O.AssignedProfsHistory, M.MatterID, O.OlderDate
FROM OlderAPH O 
    INNER JOIN Matters M ON O.Matters = M.Matters       
ORDER BY M.MatterID
```